# Detail about reactive simulatability framework

Tags: universal-composability

I'm trying to understand the framework of reactive simulatability using *"PfWa2_00AsyncModel"* from [this publication](http://semper.schunter.org/sirene/publ/) which is a tech report behind the paper A model for Asynchronous Reactive Systems and its Applications to Secure Message Transmission by Pfitzmann and Waidner.

I'm troubled with the remark 2.7 on page 6. Can anybody comment, why the configuration $conf_{1s}$ is in $Conf^f(Sys_1)$ if the port $p$ is not a port of $M_1$?